# How can i validate string before inserting into mysql?

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, node.js, validation

I am taking input string from user and storing them to database.But few days back someone inserted whatsapp smiley and I got error from database.
I dont remember the exact DB error but it was something that this value can not be inserted.
So how can i validate the string before entering it to mysql.
My application is in NODE.js

Comment: you can try to `escape` values in your string, so that you can store them into the database without any error and `unescape` them when retrieving to get its original value.

Answer (score 0):

For node.js, there is a library validator.js, which can be used to sanitize strings. Check it out. 
https://github.com/chriso/validator.js

Comment: whitelist method for my case?

Comment: yes, it would work. You just have to mention the allowed chars in RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

*edit: You can can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitizer by first running (in your terminal):

```
npm install sanitizer
```

and then calling

```
var sanitizer = require('sanitizer');
var yourString = sanitizer.escape('your dirty string');
```

The rest of the documentation can be found https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitizer

Comment: AFAIK, querystring module is only for dealing with query strings, i.e to searilizae or deserialize. On the other hand, validator.js is a full fledge validator, and input data sanitizer.

Comment: This is the same validator.js, that I referred to. :)